# Cant Print DataTable and its Values in Django Template

Tags: django, datatables

I am trying to print Datatable in Django Template. I am using Django 1.7 and using metro style CSS. If I try to return output as JSON from view , it just prints JSON output without any HTML formatting. If I return non JSON output from view it prints HTML and Datatable with heading but no values and the f12 debugger tool in IE gives a JSON error. My objective is to print a basic Datatable without any customization, I am using ServerSide ajax processing to pull data from Database(model), I have tried using sAjaxsource as well in Javascript. Here is my template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link href="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/css/metro-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/css/iconFont.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="CSS/Override.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/js/jquery/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/js/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 

<script src="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/js/metro.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/js/load-metro.js"></script>
<script src="/static/fnsbuild/metro/docs/js/docs.js"></script> 


<title>Metro UI CSS : Simple responsive css framework</title>
</head>

<body class="metro">
<div class="container">          
    <table class="table striped hovered dataTable" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">Engineer</th>
                <th class="text-left">Site_Code</th>
                <th class="text-left">NSSA</th>
                <th class="text-left">Region</th>
                <th class="text-left">GFSD</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

        </tbody>


    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function()  {
        var oTable=$('#example').DataTable( {
            "aaSorting": [[ 2, "asc" ]],
            "bprocessing": true        
            "bServerSide": true,
            "ajax": "{% url 'api' %}",
        }
        );
    });


    </script>
</div>
```

Here is my View :

```
from django_datatables_view.base_datatable_view import BaseDatatableView

class MyAjaxView(BaseDatatableView):

     template_name = 'fnsbuild/table_test.html'
     model = OspfNssa
     columns = ['id', 'site_code', 'nssa', 'region', 'gfsd']

def render_column(self, row, column):
   return super(MyAjaxView, self).render_column(row, column)
```

URL.py 
    url(r'^fnsbuild/table_test/$', fnsbuild.views.MyAjaxView.as_view(), name="api"),

Instead of Printing Datatable and values, it just prints JSON Output

```
{"recordsTotal": 79, "recordsFiltered": 79, "draw": 0, "data": [[56, "by2", "0.0.3.187", "West NA", 1111], [57, "sn3", "0.0.1.24", "Central NA", 1111], [58, "cpq01", "0.0.12.39", "South America", 1111], [59, "hk2", "0.0.4.178", "Asia", 1111], [60, "co1", "0.0.3.32", "West NA", 1111], [61, "bl4", "0.0.1.169", "East NA", 1111], [62, "co2", "0.0.3.37", "West NA", 1111], [63, "kaw", "0.0.4.76", "Asia", 1111], [64, "ch1", "0.0.0.201", "Central NA", 1111], [65, "bn3", "0.0.0.203", "East NA", 1111]], "result": "ok"}
```

I have tried almost everything suggested on Various forums, Almost given up. I am new to Django so I might be missing something silly. Please suggest.

Comment: The code formatting would need a bit of improving.

Answer (score 0):

From `django-datatables-view` [`BaseDatatableView` documentation](https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view):

> django-datatables-view simplifies handling of sorting, filtering and creating JSON output

Therefore your view produces JSON, which it would be expected if this would be used within an AJAX request.

If you need something different, you should either make `MyAjaxView` not inherit from `BaseDatatableView`, or construct another view that does something sensible with an ajax request.